# Understand if the row text is exist in the database with php

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I'm not sure about the title text because I don't know what I have to ask! If you know a better title please fix it!
Recently I making a login system with php but I have a question.
I have this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE email='$email_send'");
```

$email_send is the email that form post to my page.
Here is my question how can I understand that email that post is exist in the login_info database?

Comment: You should throw this query away and re-write it in a prepared/parameterized way, to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: @Brad I don't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: You can't simply concatenate or interpolate data directly into a query or  you risk your data being confused with the command.  If someone plugs in a quote mark `'` into their e-mail address, your query will fail.  If someone is malicious, they can exploit this data ambiguity to run arbitrary SQL commands on your database to steal data, drop your databases, or whatever they want.  If you use a parameterized query, you use a placeholder like `?` or `:email`, and then send the data separately, fundamentally separating the data from the command, preventing this sort of injection.

Comment: @Brad you think is it better I use some PHP script such as this: [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/membership-manager-pro/91421) for my user management of my website?

Comment: You can, but you could also switch to prepared statements.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  A lot of folks have to write their own user management since it is often tightly integrated into what they're building.  There are separate things you can use for authentication/authorization and they can save you time while making things more secure in theory, like you have found.  But, they aren't for everyone and every project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Assuming an e-mails are unique in your database, you can use the following:

```php
$result = mysqli_query( $con, "
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    `login_info` 
    WHERE   `email` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $email_send ) . "'
    LIMIT   1");

if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) == 1 ){
    // The e-mail exists in the login_info table
} else {
    // The e-mail does not exist in the login_info table
}
```

Using the mysqli_real_escape_string, you are preventing the SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do, validate and sanitize the email address.  Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php.  Then on your MySQL query you can use MySQL's escape string function as Malcolm recommended.